# Prove that the set $\{ x^2 + 4x -3, 2x^2 +x + 5, 7x - 11\} $ does not span $\textit{P}_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone please explain how to prove this? Also, why is it that we must create a set of coefficients for every polynomial contained in S in order to prove it and why is rank so significant?

Follow Up:
The reason that I ask this question is that the only example that I was given in my book was an example which proved the span of a subset $A$ of $P_3$ by creating a new set $T$ of all the coefficients of the polynomials in S.

However, I did not understand why the book provided this as proof. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you please tell us where do a set of coefficients and rank come into your questions? You seem to have a proof in mind that you don't understand, so it would be helpful if you wrote it here.

Comment: hint: $2(x^2 + 4x -3) - 1(2x^2 + x + 5) -1(7x-11) = 0$

Comment: @abel Where does the $62$ come from? ;)

Comment: @A.P., the caret symbol and the $6$ key are the same.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I see that there exists a unique, nontrivial, solution for a homogeneous system of equations and this is much simpler.

Comment: @Jrvgnzlz there never exists a _unique_  nontrivial solution for a homogeneous system of equations (over a field with more than two elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your other question:

Consider the polynomial $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ with $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$, and consider the mapping

$$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \mapsto (a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}.$$

It is not hard to show that this map is bijective. Therefore, linear independence in the space of polynomials of order $n$ is equivalent to linear independence in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, where the $j$th coordinate of a vector represents the $j$th coefficient of a polynomial. The vector space spanned by these vectors represents the set of all possible coefficients of polynomials generated by linear combinations of the polynomials in your set!

In this case, we could write your set $S = \{x^2+4x-3, 2x^2+x+5,7x-11\}$ as a matrix:

$$\hat{S} = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 4 & 1 \\ 5 & 1 & 2 \\ -11 & 7 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, it is clear that the first row is half the sums of the second rows -- therefore, our rows are not linearly independent. If this is not clear, we could instead compute a determinant:

$$\det \hat{S} = -3(-14)-4(22)+46 = 0.$$

This implies that the rows of $\hat{S}$ are linearly dependent. Hence, the dimension of the space spanned by the rows is at most $2$, which is smaller than the dimension of $P_2$.

Comment: emily the vector $\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.